# Change Password if, else function

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on a snippet of code for changing passwords, but I can not get my if, else function to work correctly. I can get it to either check if the passwords match or if they are null, but I can't figure out how to make it check for both constraints. Please help

```
    if (!Arrays.equals(p1.getPassword(), p2.getPassword())) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Passwords do not match.", "Woops", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if (p1 != null && p2 != null) {    
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Passwords fields can not be empty.", "Woops", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registered Successfully", "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: 'not working' is pretty unspecific. The if-then-else will work for sure.
The second test (p1!=null && p2!=null) is definitly in the wrong place, since your first test, already assumes, it is not null, by calling p1.getPassword and p2.getPassword. It will just crash, if it is null.

Comment: If one of `p1` or `p2` would be null then you would get `NullPointerException` in the first `if` statement, when both passwords are there then the middle `else if`is always true. Change the `!=` to `==` and the logical and `&&` to `||`, because if I get you right in the `else if` you want to check if any password is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you are trying to accomplish, I would recommend first checking if the password fields are empty, if they are not, check if they don't match, and if they do, show the success registration alert.

```
if (p1.getPassword().length == 0 || p2.getPassword().length == 0){                 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Passwords fields can not be empty.", "Woops", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}

else if (!Arrays.equals(p1.getPassword(), p2.getPassword())) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Passwords do not match.", "Woops", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}

else {    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registered Successfully", "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. It could have worked with the checking of null too, but consider that in your code you were showing an alert if the fields weren't null: (p1 != null && p2 != null), that's why you still got the alert when the fields weren't empty, instead it should have been (p1 == null || p2 == null).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not using if - else if correctly, I mean, you want to check, first if both passwords XX.getPassword() are the same, the also you want to check if those are not null, so I think you should put the null check as a second condition instead an else (the path if the first condition is not true).
Something like this:

```
if (Arrays.equals(p1.getPassword(), p2.getPassword())) {
if (p1 != null && p2 != null){                 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registered Successfully", "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Passwords do not match or some. Or one of them is blank", "Woops", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}}else {    
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something were wroing.", "Woops", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
```

Comment: I originally had it as a second constraint, but when I had the null as a second constraint and I type something for the password, I still get a warning for the field being null rather than a success.

Comment: Did you try to check both, ! is null and ! isEmpty?    if (Arrays.equals(p1.getPassword(), p2.getPassword())) {
 if (p1 != null && !p1.isEmpty() && p2 != null && !p2.isEmpty()){                 
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registered Successfully", "Login Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
 }else{
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Passwords do not match or some. Or one of them is blank", "Woops", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } 
}else {    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something were wroing.", "Woops", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}